# How can I properly require a library via require/npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to include underscore into my project.

```
npm install --save underscore
```

I see that my `package.json` is updated correctly. And that the library was downloaded and placed inside my /node_modules directory.

Then in my folder, I try and run :

```
var _ = require("underscore")
```

But this returns :

```
react.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'(…)
```

What is the correct way for associating a new library via npm into an app?

Comment: Are you using any other tools like webpack or browserify?

Comment: Try to delete `underscore` package from `node_modules`, clean npm cache: `npm cache clean` and try install it again. Sometimes, packages are not installed completely, because of internet connection problems.

Comment: And if that doesn't help, try running `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install`.

Comment: @PatrikAffentranger I'm cloning the TouchstoneJS package ( http://touchstonejs.io/ ) which I believe is using browserify.. I'm a hesitant about running `rm -rf node_modules` as there are other modules that are working fine in it right now

Comment: @Trip npm will read all the libraries from `package.json` which should take care of installing all the modules even if you delete the node_modules directory,